# Retrieve ssh key from github

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I had ssh key at github.com in my account. Now i reinstall my operating system, how can i retrieve my old ssh key from github and put it into `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa`?

Thank you.

Comment: the one in id_rsa is your *private* key, the one uploaded to Github is the public key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't :) because the key you need on your side is your private key which you never uploaded to github. If you have lost it, it is not a problem, you can simply [generate a new key on your system and upload the public part to github](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).